# How can I measure execution time on microsecond level?

Tags: terminal, macos, time

Is there a way to measure program execution time on microsecond level from Terminal? The standard `time` command only measures milliseconds which isn't detailed enough for my needs.

Comment: `time` already measures down to the millisecond, what kind of accuracy to you need? Also, are you interested in overall execution time (until exit) or launch time (until the started application is ready to use by the user)? Do you have Xcode et al installed?

Comment: @patrix well, I need better accuracy, may be in microseconds or even in processor ticks. The time I need is overall execution time and I need a console application for that, because I need to use it via script